# How to adjust the advance amount to corresponding bills in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to adjust/allocate the advance amount to the corresponding bills, if it's possible.

For example: Exactly advance amount is less than of invoice amount, may be if overpaid i just want to adjust the excess amount(means Invoice amt rs. 8500/- but paid amt is Rs.10,000/-, here Rs.1,500 is the excess amount) to the next corresponding bills when the excess amount turns zero.

If customer pay advance amount Rs.10,000/- I want to allocate the amount to the customer bills like: 1st bill like Rs.5000/-, 2nd bill Rs.3500/-, 3rd bill Rs.3000/-, after adjusting the advance amount Rs.10,000/- balance amount the customer wants to pay us is Rs.1500/-.

Comment: Would you add your code? I'm pretty sure this is impossible to advise upon without seeing what you have already. You may also wish to add what part of the algorithm you have tried to implement already.

Comment: Thank you for consider, i'm be blank, i have no idea how to implement this, now just get the value through using input type.

Comment: You should at least edit the question to explain more about the algorithm (please add changes into the question itself). Is it to decide the bill amounts automatically? Is one payment of 10,000 an acceptable solution? How about twenty bills of 500 each? If your customer pays an advance of 10,000 then why would you add bills summing to 11,500?

Comment: (The 1500 is not "outstanding" by the way, it is "credit". Outstanding means that the customer owes you money, but here they will have overpaid, if I understand you correctly).

Comment: i just edit in question itself, i hope it's easy to understand.

Comment: So if the bill total is 8,500, why do you want to auto-generate invoices totalling 11,500?

Comment: I no need to auto generating invoices. i just say the example for adjust the amount. actually i need if i generate 2 more invoices against a particular party. ex: First bill amount is 5000/- and the second bill amount is 3000/-they pay the amount for First bill rs.5000/-, after that they return the goods for rs.2000/-. that the amount Rs.2000/- want to adjust in the 2nd bill Rs.3000/-.